# Insert com ajax e php

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Estou tentando fazer um insert com ajax e não estou conseguindo.
entendi que para fazer isso preciso de 3 arquivos

1. html
2. javascript(ajax)
3. php (banco)

a parte 1 e a 2 está pronta e funcionando 100% mas a parte 3 me parece que tenho que recarregar tudo novamente ex: include("db.php"),("function.php")
eu carro no inicio do sistema com o autoload se eu for chamar todos dentro do arquivo php novamente fica complicado e nenhum pouco viável

segue meus códigos.

html

```
<form action=""  id="form" name="form" method="post">
    <br>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="">Ocorrência</label>
        <input type="text" required="" value="" placeholder="" name="item[no_boletim]" id="no_boletim" class="form-control " onblur="" onclick="">
        <br>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group"> 
        <label>Descrição da Ocorrência</label>
        <textarea placeholder="" id="ds_boletim" name="item[ds_boletim]" class="form-control" rows="5"></textarea>
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" name="" type="submit">Salvar</button>
</form>
```

javascript

```
$("#form").submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var array;
    array = new Array("");
    var ar = {};

    ar["acao"] = "incluir";
    $("#form input").each(function () {
        var nome = $(this).val();
        var chave = this.id;
        ar[chave] = nome;

    });
    $("#form textarea").each(function () {
        var nome = $(this).val();
        var chave = this.id;
        ar[chave] = nome;

    });



    var jsonString = JSON.stringify(ar);
    console.log(jsonString);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'model/acao/boletimAcao.php',
        data: {item: jsonString}
    }).done(function (html) {
        console.log(html);

    });

});
```

php boletimAcao.php

```
    <?php

    $ar = $_REQUEST['item'];
    $ar = json_decode($ar,true);

    var_dump($ar['acao']);//Dados chegando tudo ok.
    //die();
    $form = new GFormControl(); // parece que o sistema não está vendo a classe
    $oquefazer = new boletim(); // aqui está meu crud que é incluido através do autoload. parece que o sistema não está vendo a classe

// essa parte falta modificar para o ajax funcionar. 

    $acao = $_REQUEST["acao"];
    $pagina = $_REQUEST["pagina"];
    action = '?pagina=' . $pagina . '&acao=Incluir';
    actionAlterar = '?pagina=' . $pagina . '&acao=Alterar';

    switch ($acao) {
        case "listar";
            $listar = $oquefazer->listarAll();
            include "view/listar/boletim.php";
            break;
        case "form";
            include "view/incluir/boletim.php";
            break;
        case "Incluir";
    //        $oquefazer->incluir();
    //        $listar = $oquefazer->listarAll();
    //        redirecionar("index.php?pagina=$pagina&acao=listar");
            include "view/incluir/boletim.php";
            break;
        case"formAlterar";
            $listarU = $oquefazer->listarUm();
            include "view/alterar/boletim.php";
            break;
        case"Alterar";
            $listarU = $oquefazer->alterar();
            $listar = $oquefazer->listarAll();
            redirecionar("index.php?pagina=$pagina&acao=listar");
            break;
        case"excluir";
            $oquefazer->excluir();
            $listar = $oquefazer->listarAll();
            redirecionar("index.php?pagina=$pagina&acao=listar");
            break;
        default:
            $oquefazer->listarAll();
            include "control/listar/boletim.php";
            break;
    }
```

Meu crud (model)

```
<?php

class boletim extends Crud {

    protected $table = "tb_boletim";
    protected $orderby = "cd_boletim";

    public function listarAll() {
        $join = array(" order by cd_boletim desc");
        $ar = $this->selectAll("*", $this->table, $join, "");
        return $ar;
    }

    public function listarUm() {
        $join = array("");
        $ar = $this->find(getUrl("cd_boletim"), $this->table, $join);
        return $ar;
    }

    public function incluir() {
        $dados = $this->dados();
        $dados['dt_boletim'] = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
        self::insert($this->table, $dados);
        self::commit();
    }

    public function excluir() {
        self::delete(getUrl("cd_boletim"), $this->table);
        self::commit();
    }

    public function alterar() {
        self::update($this->table, $this->dados());
        self::commit();
    }

    public function dados() {
        $dados = $_REQUEST ["item"];
        return $dados;
    }

}
```

Comment: Tá faltando o include das classes ou do arquivo que faz o auload delas no boletimAcao.php. Coloque o erro que aparece(talvez precise ver pelo console do javascript ou teste a chamando o php diretamente.)

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa incluir as classes no arquivo solicitado pelo ajax. Como o ajax requisita somente aquele arquivo, não tem como você criar os objetos que não estão sendo incluídos no arquivo php.